# C++ error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char*'

Tags: c++

I have this C++ code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    char *Teclas;
    Teclas = calloc(1024,sizeof(char));
}
```

And the compiler is giving the following error:

```
error: invalid conversion from `void*' to `char*'
```

What does this error mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to compile C with a C++ compiler. As the error message says, this line:

```
Teclas = calloc(1024,sizeof(char));
```

tries to convert the untyped `void*` pointer returned by `calloc` into a typed `char*` pointer to assign to the variable of that type. Such a conversion is valid in C, but not C++.

The solution is to use a C compiler. It looks like you're using GCC, so just rename the source file to `something.c`, and build with `gcc` rather than `g++`.

If you really must use a compiler for the wrong language, and don't feel like rewriting this in idiomatic C++, then you'll need a cast to force it through the compiler:

```
Teclas = static_cast<char*>(calloc(1024,sizeof(char)));
```

or, if you want the code to remain valid C:

```
Teclas = (char*)calloc(1024,sizeof(char));
```

But don't do that: use the right compiler for the language. Unless this is the first stage in converting the program to C++; in which case, the next thing to do is get rid of these allocations and use `std::string` instead.

Comment: @user2792662, Which means you're most likely using GCC.

Answer (score 1):

`calloc()` returns a void*.  You need to cast its value to whatever type Teclas is, which appears to be a `char*`.  So `Teclas = (char*)calloc(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
void int main(int argc,char *argv[])
```

uhm... perhaps just `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`...

Apart from that: this looks like C code. Nothing in these lines suggests that you use C++. The error you are seeing is the result of you treating C code as if it was C++, whereas it isn't, because C is not C++, C++ is not C, and neither is the subset of the other one.

---

Compile your C code with a C compiler.

Comment: The `c++` tag suggests he uses C++.  This code uses no features that aren't available in both C and C++, so it really doesn't matter that neither is a strict subset of the other.  The commonly used parts of C are in fact a subset of C++.

Comment: @BenVoigt: "no features that aren't available in both C and C++" - apart from the implicit `void*` to `char*` conversion. This code is C, and there's no point trying to force it through the wrong compiler.

Comment: @BenVoigt "The `c++` tag suggests he uses C++" - no, it rather suggests that OP assumes that he is using C++. He's wrong (as many other people who think C is a subset of C++), and he doesn't, the code is C and not C++ and therefore it shall not be treated as such. This is not nitpicking, this is a real problem (as the question just pointed it out).

Comment: @H2CO3: The error message confirms that he is using C++.  Yes, he got his code from a C source, and will need to fix the trivial incompatibilities before it is usable in a C++ program.  But that doesn't mean he is not using C++.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: It's much easier to fix a handful of implicit `void*` conversions than add `extern "C"` everywhere, so I strongly disagree that "there's no point trying to force it through the wrong compiler".  Besides, getting it to compile with a C++ compiler is often only the first step in modernizing code, where later steps actually will use C++ features.  And I wouldn't call `void*` implicit conversion a *feature*, since it doesn't add value or change code organization.  It's a trivial difference in the conversion rules, with a trivial fix.

Comment: @BenVoigt: OK, if this code *is* supposed to be converted to C++, then bodging it through the compiler is a reasonable first step. But I see little evidence that it's supposed to be C++ (beyond the tag and the use of the wrong compiler); and if not, the right answer is to use the right compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to just compile your code with a C compiler, as this is C code. You really shouldn't compile C code as if it were C++. However, to directly answer your question, you can force the C++ compiler to compile your C code (which is very bad!!!!).

In C++, whenever you use any function of the `alloc` family, you must cast the return value to the type of your lvalue. So, in this case:

```
Teclas = (char*)calloc(1024, sizeof(char));
```

The way in which I would do the above is like this:

```
Teclas = (char*)malloc(1024 * sizeof(*Teclas));
```

The benefits here: If you change the type of `Teclas`, you will still end up with the correct allocation size. Also, I just prefer using `malloc` in general.

Additionally, you have major issues throughout your code. For one thing, `void int main(...)`???? And you never initialize the contents of `Teclas` before you print it, but you free it and calloc it again for some reason. I think you meant to make that a do while loop, but there is no `do`.

Also, `void KeyLogger();` is WRONG. That is how you declare the function, but since it is a declaration, it should be outside of main.

Comment: @H2CO3 Care to explain?

Comment: of course, [here you are](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

Comment: It's the right way to force C through a C++ compiler. It's the wrong way to compile C, and the wrong way to convert C into C++.

Comment: @H2CO3 I fully understand that in C you don't cast the return value. However, a C++ compiler will complain. It is ugly, yes, but correct

Comment: @C0deH4cker It's only as correct as compiling C code with a C++ compiler. (Would you try to run Python code using the Perl interpreter?)

Comment: @H2CO3 I know that it isn't proper C++ code. I'm just answering the OP's horrible question. Just look at his code. It's for a keylogger. He clearly has no idea how to program and probably just copy and pasted bits and pieces of code together until he ended up with this mess.

Comment: @C0deH4cker Yeah I know, but I still believe that showing him the proper solution has more benefit than replacing his problem with another one. I understand your point of view and I know how you feel, but it's not correct from a pedagogical perspective.

Comment: It IS proper C++ code, after this fix.  Not the preferred style, but certainly valid with well-defined behavior.

Comment: @BenVoigt In that comment I meant proper as in the generally correct way to do things in C++. You are correct though, it is proper, albeit hacky and bad style, C++ code.

Comment: @C0deH4cker: I certainly agree... as it also was copied from terrible style C code.  I don't understand the opinion that compiling it with a C compiler magically makes it better code.

Comment: @BenVoigt Well in general, if this were really written in C++, it would follow C++ idioms such as using std::cout instead of printf for one thing. And it is still bad code either way. The variable naming is really what gets me. Teclas to me seems like a class, not a char array.

Comment: @C0deH4cker Now that's exact! I didn't even want to get into the naming convention war, but `Teclas` is really rather a type than a variable.

Comment: @C0deH4cker: The naming isn't bad, it's just not English. "Teclas" is Spanish for "keys".

Comment: @MikeSeymour I know that it's Spanish. It's the fact that the first letter is capitalized, which generally is used for naming types, not variables. He should have named the variable `teclas`.

Comment: @C0deH4cker: Sorry, my misunderstanding. It never occurred to me that you were reading anything into the capitalisation; there are so many conventions that I never infer any meaning from it. But good luck trying to convince the world to follow yours.

Answer (score 0):

On the android NDK JNI, even with typecasting, old style or new style, the error still doesn't go away.

```
buffer = (char *) malloc(10);
xxxx=static_cast<char*>(calloc(1024,sizeof(char)));
```

To make the errors go away, an extra include needs to be added to the path and symbols.

Project -> properties -> C/C++ general -> Path and symbols

On the Includes tab/GNU C++, add the following path (with the appropriate gcc version 4.6, 4.8...) Of course on windows, the path would be be a windows path....

{NDKROOT}/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/include

Answer (score 0):

If you can make sure there is no other error in your code, you can add g++ flag: `-fpermissive` to put the error into warning.
exp: `g++ -fpermissive yourcode.cpp`

Comment: Are you sure about this approach? When the compiler has a problem, you can't always solve it by saying that it's not a problem :-)

Comment: Totally agree with you~ But if you only want to use `calloc(...)` in C++ just like in C (with no need to convert type by yourself). I think this is OK. Only use this when you can make sure your code is working, or you just try to turn c project into C++.